# iLogic (VB.NET) - DistinctBy() is not member of System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of CustomClass)

Tags: vb.net, cad, autodesk-inventor

I'd like to use [`Enumerable.DistinctBy()` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinctby?view=net-6.0) in my VB.NET code*. But I'm getting `'DistinctBy()' is not member of System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of CustomClass)` error.

This is how my code looks like:

```vb
Dim AllComponentDocuments As List(of CustomClass)

AllComponentDocuments = AllComponentDocuments.DistinctBy(Function(obj) obj.Path).ToList()
```

When I replace `DistinctBy()` by combination of [`GroupBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-6.0) and [`First()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=net-6.0) everything works as expected.

```vb
AllComponentDocuments = AllComponentDocuments.GroupBy(Function (doc) doc.Path).Select(Function(docs) docs.First).ToList()
```

Why is possible to use `GroupBy()` and `First()`, but not `DistinctBy()`? What I'm missing there?

* In fact this is iLogic code for Autodesk Inventor, but basically (pun intended) it's VB.NET code ran using eval().

Comment: Enumerable.DistinctBy() was new in .NET 6, so if Autodesk Inventor is using an earlier version, it won't work.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Oh, thanks! This does make sense .NET 6.0 is really new kid here (2021-11-08). What about other Enumerable methods - how to know which ones are safe to use when I'm limited by older .NET version?

Comment: If you go to the relevant documentation page and choose the .NET (Framework) version that you want to check against, it will tell you if the method is not available in that version. I strongly suspect that you'll need to stick to methods available in the .NET Framework 4.8 for the time being for Autodesk Inventor.